# If a SID chart says "GPS... required", can the plane use a different GNSS?

Tags: faa-regulations, avionics, gnss, sid-star

[This](http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1807/00373CWARD.PDF) US/FAA standard instrument departure says "Note: GPS or DME/DME/IRU required."

If the aircraft could tune into a different GNSS like GLONASS, could the pilot still legally fly the departure given that all other requirements were met?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FAA's standards require the use of GPS, i.e. the American satellites. This is covered in [AC 20-138D, *Airworthiness Approval of Positioning and Navigation Systems*](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1023966). It defines GPS:

> **k. Global Positioning System (GPS).** GPS is a U.S. satellite-based radio navigation system that provides a global positioning service.

It also says that GLONASS and other non-US systems are not supported:

> GLONASS is not yet approved for IFR operations in the U.S. National
> Airspace System
>
> [...]
>
> No FAA TSO exists for GLONASS, GPS/GLONASS, multi-constellation or
> dual-frequency avionics. Therefore, adding capability for any other
> constellation or dual-frequency capability must be accomplished as a
> non-TSO function until appropriate TSOs are available.

Apparently there is some kind of working group looking into using non-US GNSS but it's not possible yet. See Appendix 8 of the doc for full information.